# When trying to test laravel auth for the register rout

Tags: laravel

I'm trying check out the auth scaffolding for laravel in my project. After creating my database and migrating, I get this error when i want to test the register auth.

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (jonas, jokansey@gmail.com, $2y$10$9yqGB0hk0O5npBcsq1ImGeRYfTvkJe6ftC5QQ.nmezckbROw6CR06, 2020-05-28 16:18:49, 2020-05-28 16:18:49))
http://todaybusiness.test/register

Comment: Can you please check your table in database, check `users` table every column were there or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Your users table is missing timestamp. Check `database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php`

Add line,  `$table->timestamps();` at the end of the `up()` table,

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: @QuameNass: Please upvote and accept my answer if it has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is missing "updated_at" and mostly it missing "created_at" too, then you have to create it using migration, follow the following steps:

1. Create migration file using terminal:

   ```
   php artisan make:migration update_users_add_timestamps
   ```
2. Past the following code in your migration file:

   ```
   <?php

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
   use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

   class updateUsersAddTimestamps extends Migration
   {
       /**
        * Run the migrations.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function up()
       {
           Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->timestamps();
       });
   }

   /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table-> dropTimestamps();
       });
   }
   ```

   }
3. Then run the following terminal command:

   ```
   php artisan migrate
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly